# Entropy in multitenant environments

Tags: cryptography, random

How is entropy generated for cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator (CSPRNG) seeds in an Intel x64 Windows environment? If it uses Intel's Digital Random Number Generator (DRNG), does that theoretically mean that multitenant environments using the same host machine are more likely to generate the same global unique identifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, even though it seems different, processors only process one at a time, so even generating a GUID on different tenants at the same time would still create a unique key since:

- If on the same processor, their timing is different, even if by nano seconds, which would produce a unique key.
- If two processors at the same time, the processor's signature is different, so unique keys.

Add on to this, all the other factors used by these systems, and it would be extremely unlikely to get the same GUIDs.